# Automatic documentation of an OO MATLAB project with mtoc++/Doxygen

Tags: matlab, doxygen

I have an OO project in MATLAB and would like to automatically produce some documentation.

After some research I have found a convenient tool called mtoc++ which apparently produces a documentation using Doxygen (I have no experience with).

My only question is whether in order to use the tool I need to write comments in MATLAB using a specific format (language?) so that mtoc++/Doxygen could understand and document my comments?

If so, then what this format/ language is and where I can find its description?

Answer (score 0):

After correctly installing and configuring mtoc++/Doxygen, the documentation is created automatically.

If you want to define personalized comments for specific custom parameters, you can follow the instructions on this page:

http://www.ians.uni-stuttgart.de/MoRePaS/software/mtocpp/docs/tools.html

Look under the heading **Configuration options for the mtoc++ filter**.

What you have to do is to edit the **mtocpp.conf** file, located in **tools/config** folder, and the format you'll be using is this:

```
add(params) = <parameter1_name> => """Your parameter1 description text in triple quotes""";
```

An example would be:

```
add(params) = myVariable => """This variable is defined by me""";
```

So you can define personalized comments for your Parameters, Fields, Extra Documentation and Global Settings.

I am sure there must be other workarounds to add comments and documentation.

I hope this helps. Happy coding.

Comment: Your answer made me doubt my understanding of what the tool is supposed to do. I thought that the tool would pick up the comments (for classes, methods, properties, events) I wrote inside the code and organize them nicely in one document, the same way  _doc_ command in Matlab does it (but the _doc_ command creates documentation only for one class at a time, not for all classes of a project).

Comment: Yes you are right. That is what the tool would do. You can add comments in the Matlab source files the same way we create help documentation i.e. after declaring a function use % to add description for that function, before the body of the function. Within those comments you can use Doxygen commands to further format your documentation. All Doxygen commands start with either @ or \. You can find documentation for all Doxygen commands here: http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/commands.html

Comment: I would also recommend going through the example files, which can be found at src/docs/+examples/ folder.